# How can i change number Of Rows In each Components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

[image]

How can i change number Of Rows In each Components
i have this:

```
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return 3;
}
```

BUT this change all of Components rows number,

And The next question is : How can i Change the values in third component Like UIDatePicker : for example: in Date (in january) days are 31 but (in February) days are (29/28) an the third components must change and values will be between 1-29 or 1-28.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every picker calls `-pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` and asks it for the number of rows for each component. So this method is called three times, because you have three components. Thus you need to return different values for the components. You get an NSInteger in the `component` variable to indicate which component is asked for:

```
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(component) 
    {
        case 0: // first component has 42 rows
            return 42;
        case 1: // second component has 21 rows
            return 21;
        case 2: // third component has only two rows
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Björn Marschollek ... BUT how can i have titles with different Values?

Comment: Works in the same way. Implement the method `–pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`, use a switch statement again, but return the desired title string. Maybe you want to avoid `switch` statements and use `if` instead, because now you have two criteria to check (`row` and `component`).

Comment: Hi if i use - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)PickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component for values in each rows it gives me same rows value what should i do?

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question with a detailed description. I cannot quite get what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your need. Return different number.

```
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

if(CONDITION 1)
return 2;
else if(CONDITION 2)
return 3;
}
```

Comment: Can u answer my first question "number Of Rows In each Components"

Comment: I don't know what your components work for. So, i don't know what excatly what you put there. For e.g, you have a number selector, you can put.  if(counter_number >= 100 ) return 3; else return 2;

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number of rows for each component in the method

```
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(component) 
    {
        case 0: // first component has 12 rows for example months
            return 12;
        case 1: // second component has 31 rows for example days

           return 31;
    }
}
```

And about your second question to calculate how many rows(days) will be in the 2nd component, you have to keep a variable to store which month is selected. Base on the selected month you can keep a variable to store how many rows(days) will be in the 2nd component. Let the variable is **days** which you have to update when the selection of 1st component(month) changed. Then, you have to just changed the previous codes as follows:

```
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(component) 
    {
        case 0: // first component has 12 rows for example months
            return 12;
        case 1: // second component to show days            
           return days;
    }
}
```

Hope you will understand...

Comment: Thanks gypsicoder Can u tell me how can i have Titles with different Values like "February" Value is 1 or "December" Value is 12.?

Comment: You can keep an array of strings with the names of the months. Then return the string.